# How much does CMIS specification cover JCR specification?

Tags: java, jcr, cmis, apache-chemistry

I'm planning to use openCMIS (apache chemistry project) with my JCR repository via JCR bridge. But there is a lack of documentation for this.

Apart from CRUD of files from/to JCR repository which I just did, what about Node properties ? JCR mixins, predefined mixins like Dublin core, etc.

Let say that I have :

```
nt:file > [jcr:content , ex:content-english , ex:content-french]
```

or

```
nt:file > [jcr:content , ex:content-pdf , ex:content-odf]
```

Details on [mail-archives.apache.org](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/chemistry-dev/201106.mbox/%3CBANLkTin7+6Vb-Mn5MaTqrGZEZmpE7=YAPA@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [readme](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/chemistry/opencmis/trunk/chemistry-opencmis-server/chemistry-opencmis-server-jcr/README.txt): "Mapping is implemented as follows: JCR node type nt:file with JCR mixin mix:simpleVersionable is mapped to CMIS object type cmis:document. JCR node type nt:file without JCR mixin mix:simpleVersionable is mapped to CMIS object type cmis:unversioned-document. All other JCR node types are mapped to CMIS object type cmis:folder."

JCR properties which do not have a direct correspondence in its mapped CMIS type, are not visible through CMIS.

Comment: Considering how big hype this specification was, it got stuck pretty much and it can't do much. 2 years old essential proposal http://wiki.oasis-open.org/cmis/Mixin_Proposal was not accepted or what. Nuxeo stores their data as part of the CMIS file's properties using Dublic Core notation.  Alfresco, on the other hand, builds things in the "extended" space of CMIS properties and brings in their proprietary "aspects."  It is really f**cked up this specification.

Comment: Mixins are now called "secondary types" in CMIS and will be part of CMIS 1.1.

Comment: @Florian, have you reached a conclusion regarding http://tools.oasis-open.org/issues/browse/CMIS-713 ?